# Determinant of $2n\times 2n$ symmetric matrix equal to the square of a polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, commutative-algebra, determinant

Let $M$ be a $2n\times 2n$ symmetric matrix with homogeneous degree $1$ entries in the ring $k[x_1,\dots,x_n]$, where $k$ is an algebraically closed field.
Assume that the determinant of $M$ is $f^2$, where $f$ is an irreducible, homogeneous polynomial of degree $n$.

Is it true that we can find a matrix $P$ such that $PMP^t$ is of the form
$$\left(\begin{array}{c|c}
0 &  N \\ \hline
N^t & 0
\end{array}\right)
$$
where $N$ is a $n\times n$ matrix with $\det(N)=\lambda f$, for $\lambda\in k^*$?

Comment: What are your thoughts? This reminds of the pfaffian, but of course it does not quite apply here.

Comment: I'm working with good canonical projections (of surfaces onto surfaces in $\mathbb{P}^3$), and when we have a $2:1$ projection, using Serre-Grothendieck duality, we might prove that we have a decomposition similar to this one. By 'similar' I mean that it is not a matrix with all entries of the same degree. I was wandering if there was a bigger result that does not ask for such geometric properties.

Comment: No. E.g. $\det\pmatrix{2x&x\\ x&x}=x^2\ne-g^2=\det\pmatrix{0&g\\ g&0}$ on $\mathbb R[x]$.

Comment: I ask the determinant of $N$ to be a multiple of $f$. I don't need the determinant of the final matrix to be equal to the first. But anyhow, I will add that the field is algebraically closed.